# How to combine observables in a non-blocking way?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a collection of Observables that retrieve different data types each. I'm chaining those Observable to get all the data I want for my page.
Fact is all those informations are independent, so loading one should not block or interfere in loading the others. which I am not able to achieve.

Here is an example of what I've done for the moment:

```js
  getAll(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.getHome().pipe(
      tap((home: Home) => this.application = home),
      mergeMap((home: Home) =>
        combineLatest([
          this.getAssets(home.images).pipe(defaultIfEmpty([])),
          this.getStyling(home.styling).pipe(defaultIfEmpty({})),
          this.getCategories(home.categories).pipe(defaultIfEmpty([])),
        ])
      )
    );
  }
```

Here, the Observable are successfully chained, so I get all the data I want, but `combineLatest()` does the next request once the previous is completed, and parent emits collected data once everything is finished which creates delay.
I've been trying to use `merge()` instead of `combineLatest()` so that each data received emits it instantly to the parent Observable, but apparently I just can't do that

So, how can I manage to chain those Observables so that each submit in child Observable does emit directly to parent Observable ?

Comment: " how can I manage to chain those Observables so that each submit in child Observable does emit directly to parent Observable", this is the problem, how do you know what type is being emitted? If you want to emit into a stream, you can wire up a subject.

Comment: @AvinKavish I need to investigate on Subjects, do you have great reads about that ?

Comment: Yeah, give me a min, I also have a half written answer with subjects.

Comment: Have a look, it's only a reference implementation. Subjects can be combined in lots of different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are independent, you can handle them independently and emit them on a subject.

```
  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    const subject = new Subject<any>();
    const handler = (res: any) => subject.next(res);

    this.getHome().pipe(
      tap((home: Home) => this.application = home),
      tap(handler),
      tap((home: Home) => {
        forkJoin(
          this.getAssets(home.images).pipe(defaultIfEmpty([]),tap(handler))
          this.getStyling(home.styling).pipe(defaultIfEmpty({}), tap(handler))                  
          this.getCategories(home.categories).pipe(defaultIfEmpty([]), tap(handler))
        ).subscribe(res => subject.complete())
      })
    ).subscribe();
    return subject.asObservable();
  }
```

With this method, type checking has to be done by the consumer.

[Subjects are documented here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject).

Comment: Looks like the best answer right now, it's kinda hacky but will act exactly as I asked 
Thanks for that mate !

Comment: It's hella hacky :) You should go with @Reactangular's answer, the operator seems to be merge()

Answer (score 6):

You need `forkJoin`, it returns an `Array` with the results of every `Observable` (in the same order than `forkJoin` parameters.

```
  getAll(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.getHome().pipe(
      tap((home: Home) => this.application = home),
      mergeMap((home: Home) =>
        forkJoin(
          this.getAssets(home.images).pipe(defaultIfEmpty([])),
          this.getStyling(home.styling).pipe(defaultIfEmpty({})),
          this.getCategories(home.categories).pipe(defaultIfEmpty([]))
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't `forkJoin` just emit when all the inner Observable are completed ? That's what I'm understanding from the documentation

Comment: Yes it does that, how would you know which request sent you data if merged in the same event flow? `forkJoin` allows you to map a result to its initiator

Comment: But the issue here is that if `this.getAssets` takes 4000ms, while `this.getStyling` and `this.getCategories` would respond in 50ms, my parent obs will get blocked 4000ms instead of emitting after 50ms then re-emitting after 4000ms. Do you get what I mean ?

Comment: I definitely get it, then why not just return an `Observable[]` and then nested subscriptions in the component?

Comment: Well, I've been looking for an answer for quite some time now and it looks like using `Observable[]` definitly seem like the final answer to that issue, I'm gonna wait a bit to see what people come with but I might end up with that

Comment: Even better: just don't chain the requests in your service at all, do it in the component

Comment: Those functions are already in the component, each of the functions you see depend from a more general purpose function in a service

Comment: Oh OK, got confused by the method's name `getAll`

Answer (score 1):

> I've been trying to use merge() instead of combineLatest() so that each data received emits it instantly to the parent Observable, but apparently I just can't do that

It sounds like you're looking for *partial* data as soon as it is ready. Both [combineLatest()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) and [forkJoin()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) will only emit data when they can populate an array of equal length to the number of observables. So you either wait for at least one value in each observable or wait for them all to complete, but they emit an array and they need to know what to put in it.

I think you want to emit each piece of data as soon as it's ready.

Start by using [merge()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) to emit values from all 3 observables, but for each observable use [map()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) to create an object key/value pair for that given type (images, styling, categories).

Finally, use a [scan()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) operator to aggregate the values into a single object that will emit each property as it is updated.

Consumers of the stream can check if a property is `null` to see if it is ready or not. The stream will emit 3 values before it is complete.

```
  getAll(): Observable<{home: Home, images: any[], styling: any[], categories: any[]}> {
    return this.getHome().pipe(
      tap((home: Home) => this.application = home),
      switchMap((home: Home) =>
        merge([
          this.getAssets(home.images).pipe(
             defaultIfEmpty([]),
             map(images => ({images}))
          ),
          this.getStyling(home.styling).pipe(
             defaultIfEmpty({}),
             map(styling => ({styling}))
          ),
          this.getCategories(home.categories).pipe(
             defaultIfEmpty([]),
             map(categories => ({categories})
          ),
        ]),
        scan((acc, next) => ({...acc, ...next}), {home, images: null, styling: null, categories: null})
      )
    );
  }
```

You could add the `startWith({})` operator to the `merge()` operator if you wanted to emit a first value where all properties are `null`. As an early value for consumers so they know reading for the other values has started.

Comment: Doesn't switch map stop the first observable from being emitted?

Comment: @AvinKavish no, it unsubscribes from the inner observable when the outer observable emits a value, but it never stops the outer observable.

Comment: @AvinKavish the general rule for me. When in doubt always use `switchMap()` because `mergeMap()` can leak memory.

Comment: yeah so it transforms the stream to the new observable, consumers cannot see the observable emitted by `getHome()`. hence known as, switch ... map

Comment: @AvinKavish that's right. The stream completely switches to the mapped stream, but when the upper stream emits a second value it switches over again.

Comment: yes it does but op would like to see all values flow down in the stream, not just the switched ones, i.e. non blocking. (The implementation of the last 3 is solid btw.)

Comment: @AvinKavish I thought by "non-blocking" means he didn't want to wait for all 3 merged observables to complete. You're saying `getHome()` will emit again before they finish?

Comment: No I'm saying this has to emit 4 values for the 4 get actions. But this will only emit 3 due to the switch map. as the switch map essentially blocks the first value because it performs a switcheroo. Maybe you can augment this by adding `of(home)` into merge so that home gets emitted as well.

Comment: I'm testing it right now, let's see if it fulfills my needs :)

Comment: @AvinKavish oh, I get it now. The value of home is lost. I didn't think he needed it because it was not in the OPs example

Comment: I updated the code so that `home` is included. You can add a `startWith({home})` inside the `merge()` if you want to emit that value immediately.

Comment: Please upvote if you like this answer. I am trying to earn the bronze rxjs badge :)

Comment: I was unable to get it working as it always returns an Observable to the subscriber

Comment: @FabienSacrepeigne I don't understand what you mean? Are you get an error?